# SQL Query that runs fine in SSMS runs very slow in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have an asp.net page that loads a query which we know to run fine (within 1 to 2 seconds) when executed from SQL Server Management Studio, however when executed from ASP.NET in a SQLCommand the query takes substantially longer, I cannot seem to figure out what is happening other than one line has been added to the query since the problem started, however I cannot locate what the issue is.

The offending line of code that was added is line 6: `bi.INGR_CODE != 0`

SQL Statement

```
    SELECT  bh.JOB_NUMBER, j.DESCRIPTION, SUM(bi.INGR_ACTUAL) AS TOTAL
    FROM    BATCH_HEADER AS bh LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        BATCH_INGR AS bi
            ON bh.BATCH_ID = bi.BATCH_ID AND
            bh.FACTORY = bi.FACTORY AND
            bi.INGR_CODE <> 0 LEFT OUTER JOIN
    ServerNameReplaced.man_prod.dbo.JOBS AS j
        ON bh.JOB_NUMBER = j.JOB_NUMBER COLLATE database_default AND
           bh.FACTORY = j.FACTORY COLLATE database_default
    WHERE   ( bh.FACTORY = @Factory ) AND
            ( bh.DATETIME_DUMP >= @StartDate ) AND
            ( bh.DATETIME_DUMP < @EndDate )
    GROUP BY bh.JOB_NUMBER, j.DESCRIPTION
    ORDER BY bh.JOB_NUMBER
```

ASP.NET Code Behind File

```
//Temporary List
List<BatchItem> data = new List<BatchItem>();

string SQLCommand = DBHelper.LoadSQLStatement( "batchdescription.sql" );

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringNameReplaced"].ConnectionString);
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand sqlCommand = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQLCommand, sqlConnection );

try
{
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add( "@StartDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime ).Value = StartDate;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add( "@EndDate ", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime ).Value = EndDate;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add( "@Factory", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 2 ).Value = Factory;

    sqlConnection.Open();

    SqlDataReader DataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

    while ( DataReader.Read() )
    {
        data.Add(
            new BatchItem()
            {
                JobNumber = DataReader[0].ToString(),
                Description = DataReader[1].ToString(),
                Total = decimal.Parse( DataReader[2].ToString() )
            } );
    }
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    //handle exceptions
}
finally
{
    sqlConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: what happens if you put the `bi.INGR_CODE <> 0` in the `Where` clause instead of the join?

Comment: The result is the same. I have tried it both ways.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is generally a bad idea when you could dump that into a stored procedure and take advantage of execution plan retention etc... have a look at [this MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rajandwivedi/archive/2009/04/28/great-debate-store-procedure-vs-dynamic-sql.aspx)

Comment: I deleted my answer.  I didn't realize it was dynamic sql at first.  But you might look at this for kicks: http://www.practicalsqldba.com/2012/06/sql-server-parameter-sniffing.html

Comment: The obvious question did you run it in SSMS with the one extra line?  And use GetString and GetDecimal.

Comment: I did, the sql that is posted has the extra line in there that was added and has been causing problems. If that line is gone then all problems go away, unfortunately that line filters out data we don't want in our query.

Comment: I see you are joining to a table in another database on another server.  It could be related to that. See this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/fb714dbd-fe32-4b3f-9fb3-5d5ab1e4e2c4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are all kinds of things that could be going on.

First, Ivan G. is right that connection parameters and SET options might be different between SSMS and your ASP.NET client.  That's something worth looking into in Profiler, if you have access to it.

Second, if you've run your query multiple times in a row in SSMS, it's possible the results are being cached and that's why it runs so fast in SSMS.  If it runs slowly the first time you open up SSMS and try to run it, but then speeds up, that's a sign there's caching going on.

As for why adding one extra clause to a join could slow things down, it's hard to say why without knowing more about your tables, but it's not impossible that that could have done it.  Is there an index over `BATCH_INGR` that includes both `FACTORY` and `INGR_CODE`?  You might need one now that you're including `INGR_CODE` in your join conditions.

The best way to find out is to look at the query plan with and without the `INGR_CODE` clause and see how it differs.  Is the cost figure for one query bigger than for the other?  Are there table scans where there weren't before?  Has an index seek turned into an index scan?

Answer (score 3):

I've had to trouble shoot these before, and they're not fun, but in my experience what I've seen is different execution plans between ASP.NET & running the query in SSMS.  ASP.NET doesn't cache the query, SSMS does, but sometimes the execution plan is actually different.  The culprit often times is a bad index that is being accessed out of order, here's the guide I tend to use:

http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Answer (score 1):

It's because the query plan cache is not the same.

This is because your code and SSMS does not use the same settings and because of parameter spoofing (ie Sql Server creates the plan cache depending on the first sp execution and the parameters you sended this time) => when you execute via code and via SSMS you don't have the same query execution plan.

To be sure that you're using the same plan : tool -> Query Execution -> SQL Server -> Advance -> uncheck "SET ARITHABORT"

Answer (score -1):

Avoid calling another stored procedure inside a stroredprocedure you mentioned. This will solve your issue