# Query execution plan of same queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Observation:

I am executing the same query through .net code using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` and directly in SQL Server Management Studio by passing the parameter values.

When I execute it through code it runs for long time say (15-20min) whereas when I execute the in SQL Server with the same parameters it completes within few seconds.

The reason it was taking longer time was the performance issue of the query and it solved with the introduction of non-clustered indexes in one of the tables.

I still wonder, why it was taking few seconds earlier with the SQL Server although the environmental conditions were same. Is it due to the difference in the execution plan? Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010892/sql-query-that-runs-fine-in-ssms-runs-very-slow-in-asp-net

Comment: Hi, yes i had already this same issue. The sql server was choosing a different plan dependes of where the statment was exec. One solution is to declare your variables again in the code e set them with the parameters. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Sounds like different plans because of different session options: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html